# Typescript dynamic function by key/value of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, factory-pattern

Is there a way to set up a function based on an initial interface? I have a bunch of listOfFunctions and a an equal amount of interfaces that contain types of the functions. I would like to create a factory that returns a custom hook. The idea is to save a ton of code and make editing and adding features to all the hooks a breeze.

`FunctionInterface` Is all of the function names and their returns.

`listOfFunctions` is a setup function (the real code has a config) that returns a object with a list of functions.

`theChosenFunction` is a function that will be returned in the hook that allows me to interact with one of the listOfFunction functions. This means parameters (if needed). The functions in the real app are Promises that will set state of the hook. In this example, I just return a value and setState.

A) Is this possible to do with `funcObject[funcName]()` and create a function to invoke with typescript? This would need that ability to add params or not.

B) Is there a way to get the return value of a function type? So in this example:
`type CanThisWork = () => string;` I want to extract `string`; The idea is not to do a refactor on all of the listOfFunctions and FunctionInterfaces. There are a lot of them. If I have to create one complicated Factory, then I find this more economical.

```
interface FunctionInterface {
  noParamsNoReturn: () => void;
  noParamsNumberReturn: () => number;
  propsAndNoReturn: (id: string) => void;
  propsAndReturn: (id: string) => string;
}

const listOfFunctions = (): FunctionInterface => {
  return {
    noParamsNoReturn: () => void,
    noParamsNumberReturn: () => 1,
    propsAndNoReturn: (id: string) => console.log(id),
    propsAndReturn: (id: string) => id,
  }
}

function runThis<T>(funcName: keyof T, funcObject: T): void {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();

  // Can I have typescript set up the params here?
  const theChosenFunction = ();
  const theChosenFunction = (props) => {
    // Can I have typescript invoke the function properly here?
    const result = funcObject[funcName](); // funcObject[funcName](props)
    if (result) {
       setValue(result);
    }
  }
  return {
    theChosenFunction
  }
}


const result = runThis<FunctionInterface>('noParamsNoReturn', listOfFunctions());

result.theChosenFunction()
// OR
result.theChosenFunction('someId');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types that take a function type `T` and use conditional type inference to extract the [tuple of parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and the return type, respectively:

```
type SomeFuncType = (x: string, y: number) => boolean;
type SomeFuncParams = Parameters<SomeFuncType>; // [x: string, y: number]
type SomeFuncRet = ReturnType<SomeFuncType>; // boolean
```

---

As for your `runThis()` function,
I'd be inclined to give it the following typings and implementation, assuming you want the minimal changes that compile and run:

```
function runThis<K extends PropertyKey, F extends Record<K, (...args: any[]) => any>>(
  funcName: K, funcObject: F
) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const theChosenFunction = (...props: Parameters<F[K]>): void => {
    const result = funcObject[funcName](...props);
    if (result) {
      setValue(result);
    }
  }
  return {
    theChosenFunction
  }
}
```

I've given the function two generic type parameters: `K`, corresponding to the type of `funcName`, and `F`, corresponding to the type of `funcObject`.  The [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K extends PropertyKey` and `F extends Record<K, (...args: any[])=>any>` guarantee that `funcName` will be of a key-like type (`string`, `number`, or `symbol`), and that `funcObject` will have a function-valued property at that key.

Then, we can make `theChosenFunction` use [spread and rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to allow the function to be called with a variadic list of parameters.  So `(...props) => funcObject[funcName](...props)` will accept any number of parameters (including zero) and pass them to the called function.  TypeScript represents such lists-of-parameters as a tuple type.  Therefore, having `theChosenFunction`'s call signature look like `(...props: Parameters<F[K]>) => void` means that it will accept the same parameters as the entry in `funcObject` at the key `funcName`, and that it will not output anything (because your implementation doesn't output anything).

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const result = runThis('noParamsNoReturn', listOfFunctions());
result.theChosenFunction(); // okay
result.theChosenFunction('someId'); // error! Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

const anotherResult = runThis('propsAndReturn', listOfFunctions());
anotherResult.theChosenFunction(); // error! Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
anotherResult.theChosenFunction("someId"); // okay

runThis(listOfFunctions(), 'someId'); // error! '
// FunctionInterface' is not assignable to 'string | number | symbol'.
runThis('foo', listOfFunctions()); // error!  
// Property 'foo' is missing in type 'FunctionInterface'

runThis(
  'bar', 
  { bar: (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => { } }
).theChosenFunction("hey", 123, true); // okay
```

Looks good to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgGVckAxAVwDs0AVW+gXjgAKAB4AuOAGcYUYBwDmAGjjUJHNiABGSKAEo4-AHxxNECABtUHANxU+jZuy4AFFFBQhJBuK-cgkMDqSADxM-k48fIbWcAD0sXAA2uJSMnJKKmoa2lAAunZ0DuGcaMjwgmVsUBy8dKGOJbVI0XEJphZWFBSYJTDAEBxwmGZC+gDeFHBwlvAo3gDMk3BEMFWDE+RTUyhLAL4U+5TkcoFQmOj0EX0DAJIcp+do9BtTHBC+HpIAchCV1RKjAzGABuEGAABNbJs4G8Pp4vtkdH8OAD9EYYYioFCpmAcGBJABBDjgn7IgEQiTSWQKNEgsGQpa4iD4ongsnCCmpanyWlc9JQw4UNADaTTYDSADymCu-Q4XkEowkMtu9x0jwExheywCazgWte7zcn1JOv+wl5Yzgu0USwNcO+mPZgPRAEYbdCcXjCcSTaszUJOVT0rzhXKOgA6cwQeQB8G6d1bOBMlnEp2BtI0oFwCEJq0HLrkHpca6DKCcbgAC3FwQA0nAkCJAsSvM48ToaDWkNRlCx642kM3EEhhVBwbXlEJw1O3PJJBIUBxqIlcryF9RDIYhEW0F8PEgJDXlNuJZoAFbDmBK8ZLUOixLAlDmNhIZSSAIANUfz9y3mQ6Bg4ZsG+DAwCggSjNicC3vAMAVkgADCFYQG+HDKoMCpTuGyZzj4Rr+KcIQsIkNa5IYugSKCEJZvqUEivARCSGw5jlEMJQnueGCJNuu7+Lkk5TthuiQVMwCYMIDFMTA14elsb4wJ+T5IEIEnMUJtp5tChxTCsuo0bBCFIShaF7PmRxCnR2qMcx3hljUVaSEI+Cwnh3y-KaHD4Mo5jijAUpoQ5uhqeQKkAfpiHIQOaEQa0cAQAA1ig1AUCF4ZhYZkW9LKjmSMwNzgvgQkxToOBQAAhHAACiIh0BgSDgnAAAMcAzhoA4wJIyiaGw8DyBA8AuuGBbQc1bz6VAyBWSxtmVuKjnYayyKeWKkrSplIqjEFC59XB41IJNqVweFRlrRw0XxPWUAleVVU1YE9Uus1UDyK19wdSY3VwL18ANYN5BbWNE2SQdBkRahJ1CAARDl-h5RDhXnfFiUFtN9lCN5K3+aMyj4NDSB5QVMTncV0DlfgaF3A8Fz4NmXijc1kiSMA8gcCgmiWHAMAQAQQYKHAAA+GJaDo-NSNQWgWPgv0o7N+DDBAS3o75q3FrKAXwwkxNlVMrbMu21AEHL1PinAIDiozvNyBz9hkydFNqlTyPlqj+CaG4S2Wq7UAAikPMZKogs5MoABeEjtJYC4WlaVq6MDR0ZSrAyQ3B1AQ8oLoAEzzMoMjPursUJUlZnkEAA)

Comment: This looks promising! I will go through this in detail later today!

Comment: What if the props could be an object OR a single value? props = { id: string } or props = 99; You cannot spread if props = 99. Any idea how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand; the *list* of parameters is an array, so in `(...props) => `, `props` would either be of type `[{id: string}]` or `[number]`, or, if there is more than one parameter like `[{id: string}, number]`.  If you can provide a [mcve] of the problem you're talking about, I can look at it.

Comment: I see. You are right. As for the minimal reproducible example. This was created from code I am using on a private project and made to a minimal reduction.

Perhaps, you want to see more method examples? I can upgrades bit more of the example if you want.